# PHPUnit: null does not match expected type "array"

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to make some test cases for my below class/method:

```
class ChildClass extends BaseClass {

    /*
    Params:
        $a is of type STRING
        $b is of type ARRAY
    */
    function MethodOne($a, $b)
    {
        $c = array();

        $c[0] = $a;
        $c[1] = $b;

        return $c;
    }
}
```

And this is my PHPUnit(**Version5.7.25**) test case that I have written:

```
class ChildClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase 
{    
    public function testMethodOne()
    {
        $a = 'Hello';
        $b = array('World!', 'Welt!', 'Mondo!');

        $desired_response = array('Hello', array('World!', 'Welt!', 'Mondo!'));

        $stub = $this->getMockBuilder('ChildClass')
                        ->setMethods(array('MethodOne'))
                        ->getMock();

        $actual_response = $stub->MethodOne($a, $b);

        $this->assertEquals($desired_response, $actual_response);
    }
}
```

Now, whenever I run test, I am getting failure saying `null does not match expected type "array".`.

I am not able to find the solution for this or how to successfully write a test for above mentioned class. Kindly guide me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't that code create a stub method called `MethodOne`, which always returns `null` as default? If you want to test the actual class, you shouldn't mock it.

Comment: But without mocking how I can test the actual class. If By creating object of that actual class and executing the `MethodOne` directly, PHPUnit doesn't seem to work properly. PHPUnit returns nothing. Kindly let me know, How I can achieve it.

Comment: `$class = new ChildClass; $actual_response = $class->MethodOne($a, $b);`. Just make sure you have the correct namespaces and loaded any potential auto loaders (like /vendor/autoload.php) if you have any. If you only create and test mock classes instead of your real classes, you're not really testing your code at all.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But as said, it I try to execute the method like you have shown above, my PHPUnit doesn't work. It gives output nothing.

Comment: Please post that code instead. If PHPUnit "didn't work", you wouldn't have gotten the message _"null does not match expected type "array""_ either.

Comment: Tested the solution by Magnus and I can confirm it does work with PHPUnit 6.4.4. :-) The error you describe is most certainly caused by the stub as Mock objects aren't meant for this use-case.

Comment: Thanks all. Actually due to some missing required files, it was throwing error. Above example and solution suggested by @Magnus Eriksson worked smoothly. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You are stubbing the class under test. In order to test the class, you have to execute that class from your test:

```
class ChildClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase 
{    
    public function testMethodOne()
    {
        $a = 'Hello';
        $b = array('World!', 'Welt!', 'Mondo!');

        $desired_response = array('Hello', array('World!', 'Welt!', 'Mondo!'));

        $classUnderTest = new ChildClass();

        $actual_response = $classUnderTest->MethodOne($a, $b);

        $this->assertEquals($desired_response, $actual_response);
    }
}
```

Anyway, if you just want to test a stub from the class, you have to configure that stub to return an answer with

```
$stub->method('MethodOne')
       ->will($this->returnValue($desired_response));
```